# How would you simplify this piece of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, optimization

looking for some suggestions here to improve my coding.

How would you make this code shorter/more efficient?

```
var resultsConstructionYear = readCookie('constructionYear');
if (resultsConstructionYear == 3) {
    document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = "Avant 1944";
} else if (resultsConstructionYear == 4) {
    document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = "Entre 1945 et 1974";
} else if (resultsConstructionYear == 5) {
    document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = "Entre 1975 et 1989";
} else if (resultsConstructionYear == 6) {
    document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = "Entre 1990 et 2009";
} else if (resultsConstructionYear == 7) {
    document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = "Après 2010";
} else {
    document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = "Inconnue";
}
```

Comment: 1. use `const year = document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear')` once as the start, then `year.innerHTML` instead 2. put the texts inside an array so the numbers correspond to the indexes, then simply use `year.innerHTML = textarray[resultsConstructionYear];`

Answer (score 5):

Create an object or a Map of text by the construction year's number. If the number doesn't exist on the object use `'Inconnue'` as a fallback:

```
const textByNumber = {
  3: 'Avant 1944',
  4: 'Entre 1945 et 1974',
  5: 'Entre 1975 et 1989',
  ...
};

const resultsConstructionYear = readCookie('constructionYear');

document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear')
  .innerHTML = textByNumber[resultsConstructionYear] || 'Inconnue';
```

Comment: The amount of times I forget objects with numeric indexes are valid is annoying :)

Comment: JS The Good (?) Parts :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful indeed the numeric indexes; will also take a look at this JS book!

Comment: It's not actually related, but it's a good book anyway - https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: its called dynamic dispatch if i'm right, I always forget about `||` or `??` for some reason here and use `switch` if I need something by default...

Comment: It's called [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation). In `||` - if the 1st part is falsy (false, 0, empty string, null, undefined, NaN), the 2nd expression will be used. However, if you want to take the 2nd expression if the 1st is only `null` or `undefined`, you should use the [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
let resultsConstructionYear = readCookie('constructionYear');
let response = null;

switch(resultsConstructionYear) {
  case 3:
    response = 'Avant 1944';
    break;
  case 4:
    response = 'Entre 1945 et 1974';
    break;
  case 5:
    response = 'Entre 1975 et 1989';
    break;
  case 6:
    response = 'Entre 1990 et 2009';
    break;
  case 7:
    response = 'Après 2010';
    break;
  default:
    response = 'Inconnue';
}

document.getElementById('resultsUserConstructionYear').innerHTML = response;
```